# HTML textarea changes quotation marks making code not work

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On my Wordpress site, I'm trying to use a textarea to share image code with visitors to post on their sites. On the backend everything looks good, but copying and pasting from the textarea, it turns the neutral quotation marks (") into directional quotation marks (”) which breaks the links.

Code:

```
<textarea style="resize: none; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; max-width: 100%; height: 150px; width: 720px;" readonly="readonly">
    <a href="https://fdmotion.com">
        <img src="https://fdmotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/banner1.jpg" alt="FDMotion Custom Orthotics" />
    </a>
</textarea>
```

After copy/paste

```
<a href=”https://fdmotion.com”><img src=”https://fdmotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/banner1.jpg” alt=”FDMotion Custom Orthotics”></a>
```

Been looking around, but unable to find any textarea properties that I can change. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing how you're generating that textarea code it's tough to say, but WP uses the wptexturize filter to convert quotes into 'smart' quotes.

This article helps explain the extent that this filter is used: https://www.webnots.com/4-ways-to-disable-smart-or-curly-quotes-in-wordpress/

To the point, depending on where the content for the textarea is being generated, my guess is that at some point in its creation it's being run through wptexturize. I'd try adding the following lines to your theme's functions.php file and see if this disables the smart quotes behavior for you:

```
/** Disable Curly Quotes */
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
```

This will remove the filter from ALL instances of the_content, the_excerpt, etc, so probably not a final solution. However, it should help us narrow down if the behavior changes, and if so, which filter may've been responsible.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it right away! I kept looking for textarea specific articles and didn't even think the problem could be because of wordpress theme. Is there an important use for the smart quotes filter? If not, this is a good final solution for me.

Comment: Nope, just a stylistic thing! They look nicer, I guess? :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
<textarea style="resize: none; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; max-width: 100%; 
 height: 150px; width: 720px;" readonly="readonly">&lt;a 
 href=&quot;https://fdmotion.com&quot;&gt;&lt;img 
 src=&quot;https://fdmotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/banner1.jpg&quot; 
 alt=&quot;FDMotion Custom Orthotics&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;</textarea>
```

Comment: I tried this solution as well but it would convert it back into slanted quotes on the front-end still.